# Using application.inputbox() defensively

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following:

```
Private Sub cmdColumnLetter_Click()
    Dim colRange As Range

    Set colRange = Excel.Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Please Select Any Cell In ""Splitter"" Column", _
    Title:="Column", _
    Default:=fTableRange.Columns(1).Column, Type:=8)

    fColNumber = colRange.Column
    TxBoxColumnNum = fColNumber
End Sub
```

If the user hits cancel then `Set colRange =` fails as it is looking to assign an object to this variable. Do I have to use an On Error structure to defend against this error or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Make sure this object `fTableRange`  exist.

Comment: @Santosh - apologies - a slightly confusing piece of code - `fTableRange` is a private field within a userform declared with form wide scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to OERN

```
Sub Test()
    Dim colRange As Range
    Dim fColNumber As Long, TxBoxColumnNum As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set colRange = Excel.Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Please Select Any Cell In ""Splitter"" Column", _
    Title:="Column", Default:=fTableRange.Columns(1).Column, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If colRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    fColNumber = colRange.Column
    TxBoxColumnNum = fColNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Different syntax for assigning objects and values is, IMO, one drawback of VBA.

As such, functions as `InputBox` returning objects or values cause errors.

However, function arguments passing syntax is same.

Exploring this, I purpose and alternative solution, indeed not better then error handling solution:

```
Function SetObject(v, ByVal ExpectedTypeName As String) As Object
    If TypeName(v) = ExpectedTypeName Then Set SetObject = v
End Function

Private Sub cmdColumnLetter_Click()
    Dim colRange As Range

    Set colRange = SetObject(Excel.Application.InputBox("input", Type:=8), "Range")
    If Not colRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "..."
    End If
End Sub
```

`SetObject` accepts either an object or a value, but always retuns given object if typename matchs expected one or `Nothing` if doesn't match.